# Sine chorus effect

Tags: matlab, filters, comb

I want to create a sine chorus effect function in MATLAB where the inputs and the outputs will be: `y=chorus(x, f_sine, delay, depth, mix, fs)`. What I'm trying to do is shown in this picture

[image]

where $M$ is my $M$ sample delay operator and its given: `Μ(n)=delay+depth(0.5+0.5sin(2π*f_sine *n/fs))` and the other parameters are:

- FF = feedforward
- FB = feedbackward
- BL = blend.

What I was thinking to do is:

```
for n=1:length(x);
M(n)=delay+depth*(0.5+0.5*sin(2*pi*f_sine*n/fs)); 
xh=x(n)+FB*xh(n-M(n));
y(n)=FF*xh(n-M(n))+BL*xh(n);
end;
```

Regardless of whether it is correct my code or not, my question is that $M(n)$ could be a real number and therefore $n-M(n)$ could be a real number too. So $x_h(n-M(n))$ can't be calculated...(I have a discrete signal, I want an integer inside $x_h$). I dont know if what I'm trying to say its absolutely true (if it's not explain me why), but if it is, how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 4):

You have indeed found the key problem of building a good chorus: you need a fractional delay. Your delay moves fairly slowly with time and it's going to take on non-integer values.

The trick is the split the actual delay in an integer part and a fractional part. So if your delay 37.83 samples, you apply a 37 tap delay from your delay line plus a 0.83 tap fractional delay. Fractional delays are typically done with polyphase FIR filters. I suggest You can google it or come back with another question.

Some good reading is this http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/482137/ with Matlab code here http://legacy.spa.aalto.fi/software/fdtools/ . Unfortunately the IEEE paper is not free. You can also try this https://hub.hku.hk/bitstream/10722/46311/1/71706.pdf?accept=1 instead

Comment: Could you please tell me which m-file has relationship with my problem? because it has 22 files and i cant undertand which one refers to my problem.

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember which file does what. If I recall correctly the paper goes through many different ways of designing fractional delay filters and discusses the pros and cons for each. There is no "best" solution, it all depends on your specific requirements in terms of fidelity, computational resources, real time, etc. I suggest you read the paper.

Comment: @Gensdimi: Have a look at [this answer](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/23762/4298) for a link to the paper and the corresponding Matlab toolbox.