# How to delay an audio signal by 1 microsecond?

Tags: discrete-signals, audio, sampling

I have an audio signal sampled at 44100Hz. I want to delay this signal by 1 microsecond (and maybe even less) for a steganographic purpose. Now if I delay it one sample, the corresponding time delay will be $\frac{1}{44100} = 2.2 \times 10^{-5}\,\text{s}$. But the delay I need is even lesser than that. How to achieve it?

Comment: Related: [Shift a signal by fraction of a sample](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/23759/shift-a-signal-by-fraction-of-a-sample)

Comment: Is it a real-time application? If so, you can use fractional delay filters, either IIR or FIR. http://users.spa.aalto.fi/vpv/publications/vesan_vaitos/ch3_pt1_fir.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a "fractional delay".

A really comprehensive analysis on how to do this can be found here: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/482137/ and the design tools are still available here http://legacy.spa.aalto.fi/software/fdtools/

Comment: Interesting question/answer! Can you give the gist of it in the answer?

Comment: @Basj: The gist? "it's a complicated problem with no one-size-fits-all solution, the best design method depends on your specific application requirements and constraints". If you google enough, you can probably find a non-pay version of the article but I didn't want to post this here, since I don't know whether these are fully legal.